# Match over multiple lines perl regular expression

Tags: perl

I have a file like this:

```
01 00 01 14 c0 00 01 10 01 00 00 16 00 00 00 64
00 00 00 65 00 00 01 07 40 00 00 22 68 61 6c 2e
6f 70 65 6e 65 74 2e 63 6f 6d 3b 30 30 30 30 30
30 30 30 32 3b 30 00 00 00 00 01 08 40 00 00 1e
68 61 6c 2e 6f 70 65 6e 65 74 2d 74 65 6c 65 63
6f 6d 2e 6c 61 6e 00 00 00 00 01 28 40 00 00 21
72 65 61 6c 6d 31 2e 6f 70 65 6e 65 74 2d 74 65
6c 65 63 6f 6d 2e 6c 61 6e 00 00 00 00 00 01 25
40 00 00 1e 68 61 6c 2e 6f 70 65 6e 65 74 2d 74
65 6c 65 63 6f 6d 2e 6c 61 6e 00 00 00 00 01 1b
40 00 00 20 72 65 61 6c 6d 2e 6f 70 65 6e 65 74
2d 74 65 6c 65 63 6f 6d 2e 6c 61 6e 00 00 01 02
40 00 00 0c 01 00 00 16 00 00 01 a0 40 00 00 0c
00 00 00 01 00 00 01 9f 40 00 00 0c 00 00 00 00
00 00 01 16 40 00 00 0c 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 bb
40 00 00 28 00 00 01 c2 40 00 00 0c 00 00 00 00
00 00 01 bc 40 00 00 13 31 39 37 37 31 31 31 32
32 33 31 00
```

I am reading the file and then finding certain octets and replacing them with tags:

```
while(<FH>){
    $line =~ s/(00 00 00 64)/<incr4>    /g;
    $line =~ s/(00 00 00 65)/<incr4>    /g;
    $line =~ s/(30 30 30 30 30 32)/<incr6ascii:999999:0>/g;
    $line =~ s/(31 31 32 32 33 31)/<incr6ascii:999999:0>/g;
    print OUTPUT $line;
}
```

So for example, `00 00 00 64` would be replaced by the `<incr4>` tag. This was working fine, but it doesn't seem to able to match over multiple lines any more. For example the pattern `31 31 32 32 33 31` runs over multiple lines, and the regular expression doesn't seem to catch it. I tried using /m /s pattern modifiers to ignore new lines but they didn't match it either. The only way around it I can come up with, is to read the whole file into a string using:

```
undef $/;
my $whole_file = <FH>;
my $line = $whole_file;
$line =~ s/(00 00 00 64)/<incr4>    /g;
$line =~ s/(00 00 00 65)/<incr4>    /g;
$line =~ s/(30 30 30 30 30 32)/<incr6ascii:999999:0>/g;
$line =~ s/(31 31 32 32 33 31)/<incr6ascii:999999:0>/g;
print OUTPUT $line;
```

This works, the tags get inserted correctly, but the structure of the file is radically altered. It is all dumped out on a single line. I would like to retain the structure of the file as it appears here. Any ideas as to how I might do this?

/john

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The trick here is to match the class of all space like characters `\s`:

```
my $file = do {local (@ARGV, $/) = 'filename.txt'; <>}; # slurp file

my %tr = (  # setup a translation table
    '00 00 00 64'       => '<incr4>',
    '00 00 00 65'       => '<incr4>',
    '00 30 30 30 30 32' => '<incr6ascii:999999:0>',
    '31 31 32 32 33 31' => '<incr6ascii:999999:0>',
);

for (keys %tr) {
    my $re = join '\s+' => split;  # construct new regex

    $file =~ s{($re)}{
       $1 =~ /\n/ ? "\n$tr{$_}" : $tr{$_}  # if octets contained \n, add \n
    }ge  # match multiple times, execute the replacement block as perl code
}
print $file;
```

Comment: Excellent! Works perfectly... I never thought of using a hash map, ingenious solution!

Comment: +1 : Great  solution, just put the `/x` modifier in at the end though!